# Please help to understand what is this panic report about

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

After upgrading in my iMac SSDs, RAM and CPU I start receiving kernel reports once at 2-3 days. Please help me to understand what's wrong. Here is one of them:

```
Anonymous UUID:       F4CEE2D0-3E38-751E-DAEB-644A62A02A61

Tue Mar 17 13:10:52 2020

*** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801dedda4d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801dfe4ebc, type 13=general protection, registers: CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000010d34f000, CR3: 0x00000007c9e4d0b5, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0 RAX: 0xbfffff8085113d80, RBX: 0x000000000000e558, RCX: 0x0000000009000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000 RSP: 0xffffffa403c337d0, RBP: 0xffffffa403c33800, RSI: 0xffffff801e8024b0, RDI: 0x0000000000000000 R8:  0xffffff808969e870, R9:  0x000000000000002d, R10: 0xffffff801e6a9578, R11: 0x000000000000002d R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff808b4a36e0, R14: 0xffffffa3f83bf000, R15: 0xffffff801e8024b0 RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff801dfe4ebc, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010 Fault CR2: 0x000000010d34f000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff801db51290 : 0xffffff801ddb058d  0xffffff801db512e0 : 0xffffff801deec0f5  0xffffff801db51320 : 0xffffff801dedd82a  0xffffff801db51390 : 0xffffff801dd5d9d0  0xffffff801db513b0 : 0xffffff801ddaffa7  0xffffff801db514d0 : 0xffffff801ddafdf3  0xffffff801db51540 : 0xffffff801dedda4d  0xffffff801db516b0 : 0xffffff801dd5d9d0  0xffffff801db516d0 : 0xffffff801dfe4ebc  0xffffffa403c33800 : 0xffffff801dfe449e  0xffffffa403c33860 : 0xffffff7f9f57a9a4  0xffffffa403c33920 : 0xffffff801dff554e  0xffffffa403c33a80 : 0xffffff801dff4791  0xffffffa403c33ba0 : 0xffffff801e00d771  0xffffffa403c33bf0 : 0xffffff801e013079  0xffffffa403c33f10 : 0xffffff801e0138af  0xffffffa403c33f40 : 0xffffff801e3b9e8d  0xffffffa403c33fa0 : 0xffffff801dd5e196 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(945.275.8)[E83F6ABD-531E-3959-8E3B-EA3D1B7FC956]@0xffffff7f9f549000->0xffffff7f9f64afff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[B6CD6442-4A1C-36E6-B396-BB80DFD9501F]@0xffffff7f9eac9000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[FFD98285-1670-3317-93B7-8476794F9C33]@0xffffff7f9f170000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[AE1E0557-33D7-30A9-BC98-C442B799D4AA]@0xffffff7f9e983000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.WebKit

Mac OS version: 18G3020

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jan 23 06:52:12 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.25~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: 71EBCAB7-7239-36ED-A2B8-3DCEB0D5EFD1 Kernel slide:     0x000000001da00000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff801dc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801db00000 System model name: iMac18,2 (Mac-77F17D7DA9285301)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 190826901950805 last loaded kext at 189615704356228: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio   315.6 (addr 0xffffff7fa272b000, size 413696) last unloaded kext at 86894679828903: com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice  1.2 (addr 0xffffff7fa2720000, size 45056) loaded kexts: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.2 com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver   138.4 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.70 com.apple.fileutil 20.036.15 com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.25.11 com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54 com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.5 com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer 2.1.1 com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000 2.1.1 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy    3.50.14 com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.14 com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.1 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  6.0.14d4 com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry   1 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics    12.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking  4.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.5.9 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport    6.0.14d4 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC  2.0.1 com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1 com.apple.driver.eficheck 1 com.apple.kext.AMD9500Controller  2.1.1 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 12.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 212 com.apple.driver.AppleGFXHDA    100.1.414 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP   3.1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO  2.1.3 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext    407.200.4 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1 com.apple.BootCache 40 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib  1.0.0 com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy   1.0 com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC    1.7.6 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  10.3.3 com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC 1400.1.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 329.260.5 com.apple.private.KextAudit   1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   202 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio    315.6 com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice   1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver   138.4 com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver    2450.1 com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport 2440.4 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard   208 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208 com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d4 com.apple.kext.triggers    1.0 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54 com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 528 com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4200HWLibs 1.0 com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 2.1.1 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.50.14 com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6 com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 740.2 com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily   1 com.apple.driver.AppleSSE 1.0 com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.14 com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.18d1 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    282.54 com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily  282.54 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  6.0.14d4 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  6.0.14d4 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport 6.0.14d4 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily  6.0.14d4 com.apple.kext.AMDSupport  2.1.1 com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl  3.50.14 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    255.6.1 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   6.0.0d8 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 530.68 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    206.5 com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0 com.apple.driver.usb.networking   5.0.0 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  5.6.9 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  5.6.9 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   2.1.5 com.apple.driver.AppleHPM 3.4.1 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController  3.0.60 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac  3.0.60 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C   3.0.60 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage   301.270.1 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.1.0 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1200.12.2 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b8 com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  288 com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  4.7.9 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   6.8.6 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI  1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1 com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0 com.apple.security.quarantine 3 com.apple.security.sandbox    300.0 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30 com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage   1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM  456.260.3 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver    145.200.2 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 408.250.3 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 408.250.3 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   2.1 com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1 com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager   1.0 com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily   1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1 com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor 1 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    47 com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily 740.2 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.4 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily   2.9 com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4 com.apple.kec.pthread   1 com.apple.kec.Libm    1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto  1.0

EOF Model: iMac18,2, BootROM 180.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 4,2 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.40f0 Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560Item, Radeon Pro 560, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 16 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373141324B34334242312D43524320202020 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 16 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373141324B34334342312D43524320202020 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x16E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.3 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.9) Bluetooth: Version
6.0.14d4, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: CT500MX500SSD1, 500,11 GB USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 41.1
```

and fresh one after update to Catalina

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801697a718): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.48: expected 0x5352126e4583cc3 but found 0x45352126e4583cc3, bits changed 0x4000000000000000, at offset 40 of 48 in element 0xffffff8079b05cc0, cookies 0x3f0011a1a561b8b2 0x5352126e4583cc3"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.101.6/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:1229
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff83c30cb380 : 0xffffff80169215cd 
0xffffff83c30cb3d0 : 0xffffff8016a5a3c5 
0xffffff83c30cb410 : 0xffffff8016a4bf7e 
0xffffff83c30cb460 : 0xffffff80168c7a40 
0xffffff83c30cb480 : 0xffffff8016920c97 
0xffffff83c30cb580 : 0xffffff8016921087 
0xffffff83c30cb5d0 : 0xffffff80170c2c7c 
0xffffff83c30cb640 : 0xffffff801697a718 
0xffffff83c30cb670 : 0xffffff801697a89c 
0xffffff83c30cb6a0 : 0xffffff801697a546 
0xffffff83c30cb6d0 : 0xffffff801697af59 
0xffffff83c30cb6f0 : 0xffffff801697c5e8 
0xffffff83c30cb730 : 0xffffff8016978a37 
0xffffff83c30cb860 : 0xffffff801692e4b4 
0xffffff83c30cb8d0 : 0xffffff8016f97647 
0xffffff83c30cb900 : 0xffffff8016fb594a 
0xffffff83c30cb930 : 0xffffff7f977491bd 
0xffffff83c30cb960 : 0xffffff7f9774b2f1 
0xffffff83c30cbaa0 : 0xffffff8016f97ed0 
0xffffff83c30cbaf0 : 0xffffff7f9774b32c 
0xffffff83c30cbc30 : 0xffffff8016f97ed0 
0xffffff83c30cbc80 : 0xffffff8016f9bdcf 
0xffffff83c30cbce0 : 0xffffff8016ffaefe 
0xffffff83c30cbd10 : 0xffffff801705c623 
0xffffff83c30cbd80 : 0xffffff8016a0be73 
0xffffff83c30cbdb0 : 0xffffff8016927328 
0xffffff83c30cbe10 : 0xffffff80168fdcc5 
0xffffff83c30cbe70 : 0xffffff8016914aa2 
0xffffff83c30cbf00 : 0xffffff8016a32605 
0xffffff83c30cbfa0 : 0xffffff80168c8226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0)[C0E7E4BE-56E8-38D5-93D5-1474FEC39BD6]@0xffffff7f97730000->0xffffff7f977cffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[337B24B2-0261-3521-8D1B-23387FC1D657]@0xffffff7f97729000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: bluetoothd

Mac OS version:
19E287

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000016600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8016800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8016700000
System model name: iMac18,2 (Mac-77F17D7DA9285301)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 10269977164254
last loaded kext at 9574295825127: >!UAudio 322.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9b5b6000, size 434176)
last unloaded kext at 218834117905: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f97fab000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>eficheck   1
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@kext.AMD9500!C 3.0.8
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    322.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>!A!BHIDKeyboard    209
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4200HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.8
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
|IOAVB!F    840.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!ASSE  1.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: did you try restarting?

Comment: after restarting everything works for 1-2 days till happens again

Comment: It might be best to try and figure out which upgrade causes this issue. Take each out and test them one at a time.

Comment: as you know in iMac all is behind the glued screen. Thats why its hard to figure out which update is failure